# Para que serve a KEY usada nos frameworks?

Tags: segurança, framework

Geralmente, quando vejo sistemas que foram feitos sem a utilização de frameworks, não há utilização de `keys`.

Porém, todos os frameworks que eu usei até hoje, todos eles é necessário você definir uma `key` (chave) para a sua aplicação, para ela funcionar.

Um exemplo disso é o `Laravel`, onde você tem uma configuração parecida com isso:

```
  /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => 'A5CNJaYsFnpC9jpkbAk1nOI1ETUBsJOP',
```

Para que serve a `key` geralmente usada  nos frameworks?

Isso está relacionado à alguma esquema de segurança?

Comment: Hatters gonna Hatters :p

Comment: Isso se refere também ao `APP_KEY`? Se for eu ia perguntar esses dias atrás sobre isso também, eu até pesquisei, mas pelas respostas que obtive no fórum do Laravel eu percebi que é sempre muito abrangente, o que obtive foi algo como *App Key is used for all encrypted data, like sessions.*, mas não consegui entender como fazer isso na pratica sem laravel pra entender o funcionamento :/

Answer (score 2):

É utilizada para `SALT` de hashing no PHP

O laravel trabalha sobre biblioteca `password_hash`para geração de chaves protegidas nas senhas.

Confira:

`Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher line 30`

```
    public function make($value, array $options = [])
    {
        $cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;

        $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost]);

        if ($hash === false) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Bcrypt hashing not supported.');
        }

        return $hash;
    }
```

Esta combinação aleatória será o salt para geração da hash. Cada KEY irá gerar sempre uma hash diferente. Isso impede de invadirem seu banco e descobrirem a senha de seus clientes. Já que neste exemplo terão acesso apenas ao hash da senha, que é um hash mão única.

Nunca deixe terem acesso a essa key, pois ela é ligada diretamente ao hashing de seus passwords.

## Mas como assim? Hashing? Salt? Cost?

Vamos lá, eu não sou especialista neste setor mas tentarei lhe ajudar.

### Hashing

Hashing é método de "esconder" a senha ou algum outro texto de "intrusos".
Vamos por exemplo:

Veja esta string:

`$2y$10$ZxqbuwvAYAGvhQgl0C9Kh.q.UWCdL1eQg4SMqbrfbvnjX4rOl2AcW`

Consegue saber qual valor real dela?

Esta string é um hash de uma senha, que no caso é: 102030

Minha aplicação, com um SALT único gerou essa string como `102030`.

Isso significa hash da senha `102030` na minha aplicação será igual da sua? Não, nunca. Pois as KEYS(SALT) são únicos.

### Salt

> salt - to manually provide a salt to use when hashing the password. Note that this will override and prevent a salt from being automatically generated.

Salt é uma combinação de caracteres que será utilizada como "chave" para fazer o hash de suas strings.

### Cost

> cost - which denotes the algorithmic cost that should be used. Examples of these values can be found on the crypt() page.

Custo é o que a palavra já diz: Custo. Quando de custo esse hashing terá para o processador para ser processado? Lembrando que: Quando maior o custo, menor a chance de alguém fazer [brute force attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) em sua aplicação, PORÉM seu processador terá mais trabalho toda vez que alguém ficar digitando a senha.

Ok, mas e como aplicação sabe que o usuário digitou a senha correta sendo que é tudo "criptografado"?

Por método de comparação, jovem.

Vamos partir do exemplo que uma senha seja gerado sobre KEY x com CUSTO 10.

Se o usuário digitar senha `102030` SEMPRE será gerado strings iguais, pois a chave não mudou nem o custo.

Por isso cuidado com a `KEY` de sua aplicação, ela é importante para esse fator de segurança. Se alguém descobrir estará mais perto de descobrir as senhas em seu banco, ou se você mudá-la todas as senhas de seu banco serão inválidas.

## Correção

Laravel não utiliza o SALT para gerar as senhas, porém utiliza para biblioteca `Encryption` que é definido a key no `EncryptionServiceProvider` Fora isso é mesma ideologia.

Comment: Não sei se é bem isso... Não há nada no código capturando a informação de `app.key`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters `EncryptionServiceProvider` no register define a key do config. Basta olha na dependência `Encryption`

Comment: Vou dar uma conferida lá. Eu olhei e só tinha o `new Instance` sem nada... Você está falando do que está na app?

Comment: Entendi o que você falou. Mas parece que o laravel separou `Encriptação` de um lado e `Hash` de outro. Que eu saiba o `Hash` é usado na senha, a encryptação é usada para você enviar mensagens criptogradas e tals (O laravel tem um exemplo disso). Creio que não seja verdade que é usado nos salts (com password_hash), pois já alterei a `key` da aplicação e isso não fez com que as senhas parassem de funcionar. Pois pela lógica, se você mudar o salt, você complica as senhas salvas anteriormente com outro salt.

Comment: Tanto é que você pode observar que no primeiro exemplo a classe `Hash` não usa nada de `key`. E se você olhar o [código-fonte](https://github.com/illuminate/hashing/blob/master/HashServiceProvider.php), vai ver que o ServiceProvider não usa a `key`. Só no caso do `Encrypter`, mas no `Hash` não...

Comment: +1 A resposta está `mui buena`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters leia a postagem atualizada.